# Is there a benefit in using Lodash in an AngularJS project?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, underscore.js, lodash

Has anyone implemented Underscore or Lodash into their existing AngularJS project for a performance boost? If so:

- Were the changes something noticeable or something that you would recommend?
- Which functionality from Lodash did you find the most benefits?

I have not actually played with Lodash before and was looking into learning it. But I typically like to learn something and then actually use it shortly after, so that the concepts stick better. If I'll get some good benefits out of implementing Lodash, then I think it would be a good time to learn it now.

I do typically need to perform functions such as filtering or finding an object inside some sort of collection, so I'm thinking that's where I would utilize it the most.

Comment: Really would only use it for convenience vs performance reasons. Would also depend on how much data manipulation you need to do. Opinionated questions like this are off topic here

Comment: I dropped it because of 30-40ms additional loading time. I used filter, merge, clone, each, map, pick, but wrote my own.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well they have really different purposes.

Angular is to build an application. It helps you to structure your code and separate responsibilities between your components (modules, controllers, services, directives, routers).

Lodash is nice to manipulate collections, arrays, objects, strings, etc. It helps your code to be shorter, cleaner and probably faster. It is really well tested and documented. In my opinion, it makes your job simpler.

I use Lodash for 4 years now. I found it useful in all my projects (Backbone, Angular, JavaScript, node, in the unit tests, in the build configuration files (Grunt, Gulp, Webpack)).

PS: Lodash is also a must-have to go into functional programming in JavaScript.

Edit: [Example of searching that you can't easily achieve without Lodash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36677488/652669)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. But that's exactly what I'm asking about. I know the differences between them, but was curious if there was a performance benefit in using it over built in Angular functionality, like filtering objects. Or perhaps any benefit really, as you mentioned that you always use it.

Comment: Personally I don't use Lodash for performance purposes so I couldn't say who is the fastest for filtering. But sometime it's just really simpler to filter with Lodash than Angular. You can also think differently, like making a new array/collection from another one and use the new one in the ng-repeat. Depends of the situation, but with Lodash you have more tools to build what you try to build.

Comment: Gotcha, that sounds interesting. Thanks!