# lodash: get object from an array of objects - deep search and multiple predicates

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I have this:

```
objs = {
  obj1 : [{ amount: 5, new: true }, { amount: 3, new: false }],
  obj2: [{ amount: 1, new: true }, { amount: 2, new: false }]
}
```

And I want get one object where `new: true` and with maximum value of `amount`

```
result = { amount: 5, new: true }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With lodash 4.x:

```
var objs = {
  obj1 : [{ amount: 5, new: true }, { amount: 3, new: false }],
  obj2: [{ amount: 10, new: true }, { amount: 2, new: false }]
};

var result = _(objs)
  .map(value => value)
  .flatten()
  .filter(obj => obj.new)
  .orderBy('amount', 'desc')
  .first();
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/alexmac/sg0rcoha/4/)

Comment: Need to check if new === true

Comment: Irrelevant but if you add filter before orderBy it would be more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = null;
var maxAmount = -1;
for(key in obj) {
    if(obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        for(var i = 0, len = obj[key].length; i < len; i++) {
            if(obj[key][i].new === true && obj[key][i].amount > maxAmount) {
                 maxAmount = obj[key][i].amount;
                 result = obj[key][i];
            }
        }
    }
}
console.log(result);
```

> You still need to handle what happens when new is true and there are
>   multiple max amounts.

Answer (score 0):

Plain JavaScript

```js
var objs = { obj1: [{ amount: 5, new: true }, { amount: 3, new: false }], obj2: [{ amount: 1, new: true }, { amount: 2, new: false }] }

var r = objs.obj1.concat(objs.obj2).filter(e => e.new)
            .sort((a, b) => a.amount - b.amount).pop();

document.write(JSON.stringify(r));
```

Answer (score 0):

Alexander's answer works but I prefer ***functional style*** over *chaining style*.

With **Lodash**

```
result = _.maxBy(_.filter(_.flatten(_.values(objs)), 'new'), 'amount');
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/6nch1nmu/3)**</kbd>

With **Lodash/fp**

```
result = _.compose(_.maxBy('amount'), _.filter('new'), _.flatten, _.values)(objs);
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/6nch1nmu/2)**</kbd>